# Sequential integration test with each transaction in a separate test method

Tags: spring, transactions, integration-testing

The only way I've been able to successfully get a series of sequential transactions to commit on time in my Spring integration test is by putting each logical transaction in a separate @Transactional @Test method and put those methods in the order I want them to execute, so my test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/resources/itest/integrationTestContext.xml"}) 
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="myTxManager", defaultRollback=false)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class}) 

public class ITAccessPoint {

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void transaction1() {
        myDAO.persist(obj1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStep1() {
        /* code that depends on obj1 being persisted & committed */
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void transaction2() {
        myDAO.persist(obj2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStep2() {
        /* code that depends on obj2 being persisted & committed */
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is this an acceptable technique of writing an integration test that involves many sequential database transactions or is this a hacky way of doing it?